# What is the functional inverse (with respect to $h$ (!)) of $f^{\circ h}(x)={F(h) +x F(h-1) \over F(1+h) +x F(h) }$?

Tags: functional-analysis, special-functions, fibonacci-numbers, function-and-relation-composition, complex-dynamics

I've considered the fractional iteration of $f(x) = {1 \over 1+x} $ for which the general expression depending on the iteration-height parameter $h$ might be assumed by the formula 
$$ f^{\circ h}(x) = f(x,h)={F(h) +x \cdot F(h-1) \over F(1+h) +x \cdot F(h)  }$$  where
$ \displaystyle \qquad \small F(h)=\operatorname{fibonacci}(h) = {\varphi^h - (1-\varphi)^h \over \sqrt5 }$ and

$ \displaystyle \qquad \small \varphi = {1+\sqrt5 \over 2} \sim 1.618... $

*(Note, that for fractional iterates we need $x \in \mathbb C$)*

Today I tried to find a formulation for the functional inverse with respect to *h*, but don't find a good starting point so:

***Q:*** How would look a function $ h = \operatorname{hgh}(x_0,x_h) $ which would indicate the required iteration-height $h$ given $x_0$ and $x_h = f(x_0,h)$ ? Is there even a closed form for it (I'd call it still closed-form  if it possibly includes e.g. the Lambert-W function)

*[update]: for more background see [the older exercise of mine](http://go.helms-net.de/math/tetdocs/FracIterAltGeom.htm)*

Comment: Sorry if I can't help you, but I'm very interested.Using the superfunctions' terminology, what you are searching is inverse of the $x_0$-based superfunction of $f$, lets call the superfunction $\mathcal S [f]_{x_0}$ then we have $\mathcal S [f]_{x_0}(h)=f^{\circ h}({x_0})=x_h$, and we have $i)$ $\mathcal S [f]_{x_0}(0)={x_0}$

$ii)$ $f(\mathcal S [f]_{x_0}(h))=\mathcal S [f]_{x_0}(h+1)$

In other words you search the abel function of $f$: $h=\mathcal S [f]_{x_0}^{\circ -1}(x_h)$

Comment: @MphLee: see my own answer for the/a possible solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fractional linear transformation $f$ can be represented by the $2\times 2$ matrix $\displaystyle \left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{array}\right)$, which is diagonalized as
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{array}\right)=
P\left(\begin{array}{cc} \varphi & 0 \\ 0 & 1-\varphi\end{array}\right)P^{-1},\qquad 
P=\left(\begin{array}{cc} \varphi-1 & -\varphi \\ 1 & 1\end{array}\right).$$
Therefore the matrix corresponding to $h$th iteration is
$$P\left(\begin{array}{cc} \varphi^h & 0 \\ 0 & (1-\varphi)^h\end{array}\right)P^{-1}=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\begin{array}{cc} (\varphi-1)\cdot\varphi^h +\varphi\cdot(1-\varphi)^h & \varphi^h -(1-\varphi)^h \\ \varphi^h -(1-\varphi)^h & 
\varphi\cdot\varphi^h +(\varphi-1)\cdot(1-\varphi)^h \end{array}\right)$$
and we obtain
$$\left(\frac{1-\varphi}{\varphi}\right)^{h}=\frac{x_hx_0+\varphi x_h-(\varphi-1)x_0-1}{x_hx_0-(\varphi-1)x_h+\varphi x_0-1}.$$
Taking the logarithm, one finds the expression
$$\mathrm{hgh}(x_h,x_0)=\ln\frac{x_hx_0+\varphi x_h-(\varphi-1)x_0-1}{x_hx_0-(\varphi-1)x_h+\varphi x_0-1}\Bigl/\Bigr.\ln\frac{1-\varphi}{\varphi}.$$
Note, however, that the expressions in the logarithms can become negative or even complex (in the denominator logarithm it is always negative), so some care should be taken to choose correct branches.

Comment: "Does it answer...": Hmm, don't see it yet (but this might occur later). At least the hint with the matrices/diagonalization should have come to me myself, thanks for this! And possibly the height-function is just derivable using the log of the diagonal-matrix ($ \to $ Abel-function). I'll look at it later in the evening

Comment: O.L. - "Does it answer...?" I think I've got it myself now, see my own answer.

Comment: O.L.: I'd like to put the accept-mark at your answer now because it is correct and your answer was here far quicker than mine. Only, for some possible later readers of this thread it would be better, if the accepted answer contained also the explicit expression for the solution (the hgh-function and the logarithm) and also possibly a remark about the multivaluedness and that the $z_n$ are in fact the $x_n$ of the question. Would you mind to include that things?

Comment: @GottfriedHelms: I have changed the notation and included the logs. The issue of multivaluedness is mentioned but not discussed much. Actually when you continue a function defined on some discrete subset of complex plane to the whole plane, the continuation is far from unique: for example, we could multiply the left side of the relation before the logarithms by $\cos2\pi h$ or $e^{2\pi i h}$ and it would still be correct - but that would give a different function $\mathrm{hgh}(x_h,x_0)$.

Comment: (accepted) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Ahh, the hints to the matrices and to the superfunction were useful. They forced me to look more seriously in my own exercise - and of course the Abel-function is the log of the Schröder-function and in the exercise I've already defined a very simple series for the Schröder-function.

Let's denote $ \small \beta = \varphi-1 \sim 0.618...$ and $ \small u =-\beta^2$ then according to my own formula 2.7 the (recentered) Schröder function is
$$ \sigma (t) = -\sqrt5 \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-{t \over \sqrt5})^k $$ and the inverse schröderfunction 
$$ \sigma^{-1} (t) = \sqrt5 \sum_{k=1}^\infty ({t \over \sqrt5})^k $$ 
such that the continuous iterate is
$$ f(x,h) = \sigma^{-1} \left(u^h \cdot \sigma( x - \beta) \right) + \beta $$

The height-function $hgh(x_h,x_0)$ can be taken from the logarithm to the base $u$ of the ratio of the schröder-values as
$$ \operatorname{hgh}(x_h,x_0) = \log_u \left({ \sigma(x_h - \beta) \over \sigma(x_0-\beta) } \right) $$
and if we use the fact, that the Schröder-function is just a geometric series and can be expressed in a closed form we get finally:
$$ \operatorname{hgh}(x_h,x_0) = \log_u \left(
 {x_h-\beta \over x_0 - \beta } \cdot{  \sqrt5 + x_0-\beta 
 \over \sqrt5 +  x_h-\beta } \right) $$

Because $u$ is negative we get complex values for fractional $h$ and this must then be handled by selection of the correct branch of the complex logarithm.

Also it must be handled, that the trajectory of iterations with real heights form a spiral through the complex plane with one round per *2* units in the height and thus the winding-number for heights $h \ge 2 $ must be reflected, say for the example $hgh(2/3,1) = 2$ we need to introduce that correction writing/branching of log
$$ \cdots = { \log \left({ \sigma(x_h - \beta) \over \sigma(x_0-\beta) } \right) + 2 \pi i\over \log u} $$ otherwise we get "the shortest distance" expressed by a complex height of $\small 0.171595 + 0.560130 i$ instead.

But that are details which I can now work on by myself. Thanks for the hints - sometimes one needs only an external impulse to recover a unremembered concept ...

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea what is called Abel/Schroder function, but your formula for $\mathrm{hgh}(x_h,x_0)$ is indeed the logarithm of my last one.

Comment: @O.L.: By the general concept, the finding of the Schröder-function is equivalent to your $P$and $P^{-1}$ diagonalization. It allows then to express iterates of a function by powers of the diagonal-matrix as in your example. I didn't expect that the result would be one which could be expressed using 2x2-matrices only and so I left your example aside when I re-worked the thing - only to arrive at a rational function which finally needs only 2x2-matrices for its representation... That's ironic a bit... I'll check now, whether our answers are indeed the same, thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @O.L.: also Schröder/Abel-function can for instance be found in wikipedia at least in the page about "tetration", and there is a relation to the concept of "carleman-matrix" (in wikipedia too) in terms of the diagonalization of the carleman-matrix associated to a function.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Glad it helped you (even if I don't even understand well how you and O.L.) did find the exat solution (xD I don't even know what is a matrix).